# NSDateComponents behaving strange in the first week of 2012

Tags: ios, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

In my iOS app I have to create a week based on the current date.

This is the piece of code:

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[components setYear:year];
[components setWeek:week];
[components setWeekday:2];

NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDate *date = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];
```

In this particular case the year is 2012 and the week is 1. I would expect the calendar to return 2012-01-02, as that is the date of monday in week 1 / 2012. But instead it returns 2012-12-30.

UPDATED with Timezone:

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];    
[components setYear:2012];
[components setWeek:1];
[components setWeekday:2];

NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
[gregorian setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
NSDate *date = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];
```

Still returns 2012-12-30.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found out that this code behaves as you expect

```
[components setYearForWeekOfYear:year];
[components setWeekOfYear:week];
[components setWeekday:2];
```

It looks legit but the document does not say much so use it at your own risk. ^ ^

Comment: @hufkens I'm positive that the result date is 2012-01-02 when local timezone applied. What is your result?

Comment: No matter what I add as a Timezone it always returns 2012-12-30. I tried with: [gregorian setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]]; or [gregorian setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"CET"]]; or [gregorian setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];

Comment: The code can be found in the original message. The example is with the localTimeZone.

Comment: You did not use the method that I suggested?

Comment: Thanks for helping out, but what exact method are you referring to? I applied the localTimeZone to the NSCalendar in the updated example.

Comment: `[components setYearForWeekOfYear:year];
[components setWeekOfYear:week];
[components setWeekday:2];` as in my answer.

Comment: I overlooked the differences in the code. My mistake. It works indeed. Thanks a lot!